# Registering new dependency

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

I am using [asp.net boilerplate](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com) to create new project.

I have defined new service as follows:

```
public class Employee : Entity<int>
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployeeAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Employee AddEmployee(Employee emp);
    List<Employee> GetAll();
}

public class EmployeeAppService : MyTestProjectAppServiceBase, IEmployeeAppService
{
    private IRepository<Employee, int> _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeAppService(IRepository<Employee, int> repo)
    {
        _employeeRepository = repo;
    }

    public Employee AddEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        return _employeeRepository.Insert(emp);
    }

    public List<Employee> GetAll()
    {
        return _employeeRepository.GetAllList();
    } 
}
```

I want to use the service in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : MyTestProjectControllerBase
{
    IEmployeeAppService service;

    public HomeController(IEmployeeAppService svc)
    {
        service = svc;
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get following error:

> Can't create component 'MyTestProject.Services.EmployeeAppService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'MyTestProject.Services.EmployeeAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[[MyTestProject.Domain.Employee,
>   MyTestProject.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' which was not
>   registered.

How do I register the `EmployeeAppService` dependency with `HomeController`?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following code

```
IocManager.Register(typeof(IRepository<Employee, int>),
                    typeof(EmployeeAppService),
                    Abp.Dependency.DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

but then it displays this error

> There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.

Comment: Where/How do you register your dependencies, or have you not got DI working at all yet?

Comment: not got DI working, this is my first service which I want to register

Comment: You need to read the docs: http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection

Comment: `IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention` auto registers dependancies, I wonder why its not taking my new service

Comment: Also, your controllers should inject *interfaces* in the constructor not *concrete classes* (more likely to be your problem).

Comment: changed to `IEmployeeAppService ` from `EmployeeAppService `, still getting same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This normally happens when your Entity (Employee in this case) is not specified in you DbContext.

Just add the following property to your DbContext class and you should be good to go:

`public virtual IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }`

Comment: Where is IDBSet?... having the same issue above.

Comment: It is in the System.Data.Entity namespace in the EntityFramework assembly

Comment: Thanks, but my Project is EFCore, there is not IDbSet yet...  that´s what had me confused.

Comment: Ah... For EF Core, that should just be ```public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }```

Comment: for those who struggled with this issue ... virtual keyword is important for this to work even if you declared your entity in DbContext

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register application service manually. Remove the code 
*IocManager.Register ...*

When you base from IApplicationService it's automatically registered to DI.

Error says EmployeeAppService cannot be resolved. So just like *Jacques Snyman* said, add the Employee entity to DbContext.